# Turtle polygon boundary location

Tags: python, math, turtle-graphics

I am studying Python, specifically, functions with turtle graphics

I have started with some diamond-shaped polygons that made a nice shape. I then tried to create a 10-sided polygon with each point connecting with the outer points of the diamonds. Here are the diamonds without the 10-sided polygon:

[image]

I'm trying to find the distance between each outer point of the diamonds, and the degree at which they turn, as these will be the correct degree 
(`pen.right()`) and length (`pen.forward()`) to use to create the 10-sided polygon. I've tried guessing the length and degree values (as seen below under "# make the polygon") but I can't make it look right.

Is there a way to mathematically calculate the length and degree the turtle pen should draw to create the polygon?

Also if anyone has a suggestion on how I can improve my drawing I'd definitely love to hear it!

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import *
import turtle
import random

# draw flower
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(10)
turtle.Screen().bgcolor("grey")
colours = ["cyan", "purple", "white", "blue"]
pen.color("cyan")

for i in range(10):
    for i in range(2):
        pen.forward(100)
        pen.right(60)
        pen.forward(100)
        pen.right(120)
    pen.right(36)
    pen.color(random.choice(colours))
# end flower

# direct pen to point to make polygon

pen.up()
pen.right(36)
pen.forward(100)
pen.right(60)
pen.forward(100)
pen.right(60)
pen.down()

# make the polygon
pen.right(21)
pen.forward(106)

for i in range(9):
   pen.right(37)
   pen.forward(100)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm doing a conversion masters in Interactive Media so it's all very new to me. I'll try editing my post now

Comment: I inserted a graphic of what your figure looks like without the outer 10-sided polygon. I also increased the indentation of your `pen.color(random.choice(colours))` line to correct the syntax. Let me know if either is not what you wanted. You do realize that your figure is not a fractal? Are you trying to use basic shape to make a fractal?

Comment: You helped a lot thank you! Yeah I'm making the shape first and then I'll begin to make it a fractal, I'm taking the scenic route.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest a non-mathematical solution to your problem.  Since you've had the pen at each of these points at some time during the drawing of the petals, all you need to do is save the position of the turtle at that moment, and then later revist all these positions.  This solution should be exact even if the math isn't:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice

COLOURS = ["cyan", "purple", "white", "blue"]

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("grey")

pen = Turtle()
pen.speed('fast')

# draw flower
points = []

for _ in range(10):
    pen.color(choice(COLOURS))

    for flag in range(2):
        pen.forward(100)
        pen.right(60)
        pen.forward(100)
        pen.right(120)

        if not flag:
            points.append(pen.pos())

    pen.right(36)
# end flower

# direct pen to point to make polygon

pen.up()
pen.color(choice(COLOURS))

for point in points:
    pen.goto(point)
    pen.down()

pen.goto(points[0])
pen.hideturtle()

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could explain the geometry and trigonometry involved to find the answer to your questions, but this site is not set up to use MathJax, which would make the equations easier to type and show. Instead, I'll just show the answer in code. These distances do not give the exact points, since the actual mathematical values for the distances are irrational, though the angles are exact. But these seem to be good enough for your purpose. I kept the color random for the 10-sided polygon: you can easily change that color if you like.

Replace the end of your code with:

```
# direct pen to point to make polygon
pen.up()
pen.right(30)
pen.forward(173.21)
pen.right(108)
pen.down()
for i in range(10):
    pen.forward(107.05)
    pen.right(36)
```

Combined with the start of your code, I got this graphic on one run:

[image]

One suggestion for improvement: the outer polygon for your figure has top and bottom sides that are almost horizontal but not quite. If you rotate the figure `6°` clockwise or `30°` counterclockwise, those sides become horizontal, which looks better. Add the line `pen.right(6)` (or `pen.left(30)`) before your first `for` loop and you get this:

[image]

Comment: So impressive thank you very much! I can't understand how you figured out the points I was trying for days. Thanks again.

Comment: @NancyCollins: Your are welcome. On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer, if you have enough reputation to do so. In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered. So choose which answer helped you the most and accept it. Both these answers are good, for different reasons.